# NullPointerException while running Maven tests from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nullpointerexception, automated-tests

I am trying to run maven test cases from Jenkins but its throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 6, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.662 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] TestSuite.CoD_Regression_Test_Suite.TC01_verifyRegistrationFromCheckoutPage  Time elapsed: 0.031 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestSuite.CoD_Regression_Test_Suite.TC01_verifyRegistrationFromCheckoutPage(CoD_Regression_Test_Suite.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:962)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
```

I did try to resolve it but no luck.

The test are reading from pom.xml which is getting fetched from github repo

Comment: Hi!  There doesn't appear to be enough information to figure out why `TC01_verifyRegistrationFromCheckoutPage` would be throwing a `NullPointerException` on line 197.  At a minimum, we'd need to see the code under test, including that line of code..

Comment: Also: do you get the same `NullPointerException` when you run the Maven project on your local machine?

Comment: It does work on local @M.Justin

Comment: OK, thanks.  The fact remains, however, that we can't really help without seeing the failing portion of the test, including line (`TestSuite.CoD_Regression_Test_Suite.TC01_verifyRegistrationFromCheckoutPage(CoD_Regression_Test_Suite.java:197)`)